# Eliminate The Need For Casting

Tags: java, interface

I am busy writing an API which modifies a graph. To control what I am exposing to the users of the API I am using interfaces.

The interfaces exposing the methods which will be used are as follows. Essentially this is what the user will see:

```
public interface GraphEditor{
    Edge addEdge(AsbtractNode f, AbstractNode t)
}
public interface AbstractNode{
}
public interface ExampleNode1 extends AbstractNode{
}
public interface ExampleNode2 extends AbstractNode{
}
```

The implementation structure is:

```
public class GraphEditorImpl implements GraphEditor{
    public Edge addEdge(AsbtractNode f, AbstractNode t){
        AbstractNodeImpl from = (AbstractNodeImpl) f;
        AbstractNodeImpl t = (AbstractNodeImpl) f;
        from.getVertex().addEdge(t.getVertex);
    }
}
public class AbstractNodeImpl implements AbstractNode{
    Vertex vertex; //Must remain hidden from users
    public Vertex getVertex(){
        return vertex;
    }
}
```

Inside graph editor I have a method which allows the user to add and edge between two nodes `addEdge`. This method has to cast `AbstractNode` to `AbstractNodeImpl` in order to access the `getVertex()` method which is needed to get the 'Vertex'.

I cannot expose `getVertex()` within the `AbstractNode` interface as I cannot have users working with the `Vertex` directly. Is there any way to achieve this sort of functionality without having to cast from the interface into the implementation?

Comment: But since the users already have the `AbstractNode` object, can't they just cast it to `AbstractNodeImpl` and call `getVertex()` anyways?

Comment: What is so sensitive about `Vertex` that you don't want users to access? What stops them accessing it reflectively, or by casting?

Comment: `AbstractNodeImpl t = (AbstractNodeImpl) f;` is probably a typo...?

Comment: How are you passing the values to addEdge?

Comment: Your current model will not work. The logical model would be that the `AbstractNode` class is supposed to contain enough information to identify the node, while the `GraphEditor` model contains all the methods to modify the graph

Comment: "I cannot expose getVertex() within the AbstractNode interface as I cannot have users working with the Vertex directly" .... And then you cast it so its accessible ...Seems to me you do want it exposed ... Make it part of your AbstractNode interface and be done with it

Comment: @AJC As I said I am trying to avoid casting. The current model works but I am wondering if there is anyway to avoid the casting as it seems risky and messy as there is no gaurentee that the cast to `AbstractNodeImpl` will be successful. Other classes could implement `AbstractNode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current model will not work. You can make it so that the `AbstractNode` interface only contains information on on the node, and the `GraphEditor` interface contains all the methods need to edit the graph:

```
interface AbstractNode {
    // identify this node
    // this class only contains the ID of this node
}

interface GraphEditor<T extends AbstractNode> {
    // this class stores the graph
    void addEdge(T a, T b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the function `addEdge(AbstractNode)` to the `AbstractNode` interface.

The implementation of this function can be `getVertex().addEdge(that.getVertex)` or whatever is appropriate to the implementing class.

And if you don't want people to be able to access the `Vertex` instance, make `getVertex()` private or protected.

Comment: @Simo - it's in the `GraphEditor` interface, not the `AbstractNode` interface.

Comment: This wont work. For example: `n1.addEdge(n2)`, you will be able to access `n1` vertex directly (because the add edge implementation will be in `AbstractNodeImpl`) but you cannot access the Vertex of `n2` because `n2` is still an `AbstractNode` which cannot access `getVertex`. You would still need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad design using a type as a parameter and cast it to a different subtype inside the method.

What happens if a user create a custom class that extends `AbstractNode`?

You need to consider also that when you write an API.

If there is no other possibility you need to check in your code that the real type of the parameter is AbstractNode, if not you need to throw at least an [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)

Comment: The design flaw is in crippling the client's ability to do work within the given API. It seems evident the poster requires access to the Vertex and as such should make it part of the interface.

Comment: So the type of the parameter should be a type that can access the Vertex and no cast is needed.